# How to extract a custom icon from an application in macOS?

Tags: macos

I applied a custom icon to an application by copying and pasting it into the "Get Info" window.

I then lost the original file.

Is there any way to extract the custom icon back out? Copying and pasting out of the "Get Info" doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always copy an icon to clipboard. This will let you copy an existing app icon to clipboard and paste it in tools that support image editing (Microsoft Powerpoint/Photoshop/etc.):

1. Right click on app/file with customized icon and select "Get Info"
2. Click on the icon at the corner and copy by "`command+c`"
3. Paste the icon by "`command+v`" in a photo editing app

In Mac OS, all icons are physically accessible in specific path inside `Library`:

1. Open a new Finder window from the Mac OS X Desktop and hit `Command+Shift+G` (or go to the “Go” menu and choose “Go To Folder”
   Paste in the following complete file system path in Go To Folder:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/
```

2. Choose “Go”. You’ll be brought to the appropriate resources folder containing all system icons for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice write up here on how to use Preview to do this (just copy from Finder, and "New from Clipboard" in Preview): https://www.howtogeek.com/687389/how-to-extract-a-high-quality-icon-from-a-mac-app/

You can also paste into other Mac apps, like Graphic Converter, in case you'd like to save it as a real ICNS file.

Or just search "mac icon extract" for other tools/ways to do it!

The Op said this method didn't work, so let me share a vid/gif of this working, at least for me, so you can see the button clicks.  I applied a custom icon on top of a regular app (using Finder!), and then did this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmDaQ.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work for me - the only icon within the package contents is the original one that shipped with the app. I am looking to get my own custom icon which I applied as explained in my question.

Comment: I don't have GraphicConverter, but I have `Image2icon` and the process with it is dead simple: drag and drop an app into `Image2icon`, then export.